# Perimeter convexity calculation - Matlab

Tags: matlab

The regionprop function in matlab can calculate 'ConvexArea' and 'ConvexHull', how can I calculate the Perimeter convexity based on these data?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;

a =   imread('circlesBrightDark.png');

bw = a < 100;
imshow(bw)
title('Image with Circles')
stats = regionprops('table',bw,'Centroid','ConvexHull')

k=2
outlineConvex = stats.ConvexHull{k};
P = perimeter(outlineConvex);
```

Comment: What do you mean with Perimeter convecity? As I understand, the perimeter is the distance around the boundary of the region. This is also a property of regioprops.

Comment: The 'Perimeter' is the distance around the boundary of the region. I wish to find the convex polygon perimeter.

Comment: @hsi You want to find the length of the perimeter, or you want to use some metric to measure the degree of convexity of the perimeter? The phrasing of your question is unclear.

Comment: I wish to sum the distances between each adjoining pixels pair of the convex hull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convexity is typically defined as the ratio of the perimeter of the convex hull to the perimeter of the object. It is a little hard finding the perimeter of the convex hull using `regionprops`, because this feature is not built in. This should work:

```
stats = regionprops(bw,'Perimeter','ConvexImage');
for ii=1:length(stats)
   cp = regionprops(+stats(ii).ConvexImage,'Perimeter');
   stats(ii).Convexity = cp(1).Perimeter / stats(ii).Perimeter;
end
```

(I don't have MATLAB on hand right now to test this, Octave doesn't implement the 'ConvexImage' feature.)

Using the [DIPimage toolbox](http://www.diplib.org/), you can do as follows:

```
msr = measure(bw,[],{'Perimeter','ConvexPerimeter'});
Convexity = msr.ConvexPerimeter ./ msr.Perimeter;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two questions: 1) what is the meaning of +stats(ii)? , 2) how can I all the stats(ii).Convexity results in cell array.

Comment: @hsi: 1) `+bw`, with `bw` a logical array, converts it to non-logical, without changing the values. So it turns the binary image into a labeled image with only one label. This prevents `regionprops` from running `bwlabel` or whatever it does. 2) To get all values in a struct array into a cell array, do: `{stats.Convexity}`. But I would use a numeric array instead: `[stats.Convexity]`. This is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the convex hull of a binary image and then calculate the perimeter of this image.

```
%   Binarize image
bwImg = imbinarize(image);

%   Generate convex hull image from binary image
convexHull = bwconxhull(bwImg);

%   Calculate the perimeter of the convex hull
ConvexHullPerimeter = regionprops(convexHull, 'Perimeter');
```